# Junk Chars sent in message body when sending MQ message using jmsTemplate in Spring

Tags: spring, ibm-mq

I am using jmsTemplate to send messages to MQ Queue. When the consuming MQ application gets the message they are able to see junk chars like below in message. I need to remove them as they are causing parse exception.

> ```
> WS-OUTPUT-BUFFER:RFH �����*����4MQSTR   ������Ï´���∑∞_é¥û∞(Ω¥û|_Ω™æµ¬æ∞(Ω¥û∞_é¥û∑∑���ë∞|_Ωû∞ÖΩæûêÛµÛµÈä§É†âÉ
>  Ñ<…§(â§+äàâäà†&<·∞ÖΩæû∞ä_Ωû⁄ﬂ‡Â›Âﬁ„ﬁ∞ä_Ωû∞Ñ•¥û§ÖÈé›µ¥„ﬁŸé›µ¥„µﬁŸﬁŸﬁŸﬁŸﬁŸﬁŸﬁŸﬁŸ¥‡éﬁﬂé›∂éé„„ﬁ„⁄Ÿ∞Ñ•¥û∞Ö%¿û∞Ö
>  %¿û∞|_Ωû���∫∞ÛΩºû∞ÑÑâ§Ö∑¥æ±•ﬁû„⁄Â∞ÑÑâ§Öû∞∂/•%§∂ÇÛ•µΩéµ∑¥æ±•ﬁû⁄∞∂/•%§∂ÇÛ•µΩéµû∞µ>é?¥•>è∑¥æ±•ﬁû›∞µ>é?¥•>èû∞ÛΩ
>  ºû∑∑∑<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> ```

Comment: Make sure your configuration of the JMS stuff is correct and matches the MQ configuration (like message type etc.).

Comment: Check for a `targetClient` setting.   This defaults to JMS which places a RFH2 header on the message.  Older consuming apps can see this as part of the message body.   The receiving app can also specify `MQGMO-NO-PROPERTIES` to cause MQ to strip off the header, they would need to be at v7.0 or later.

Comment: Can the receiving application deal with MQRFH2 headers?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue when the receiving application could not handle the MQRFH2 header.

Therefore I had to set the [TARGCLIENT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q112610_.htm) (short `TC`) property with `WMQ_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ` (value `1`) on the JMS Destination object like this:

```
<Resource
        name="jms/YOUR.QUEUE.NAME"
        auth="Container"
        type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue"
        factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueFactory"
        QU="YOUR.QUEUE.NAME"
        TC="1"/>
```

See also [Exchanging messages between a JMS application and a traditional IBM MQ application](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032070_.htm).